# Problem Loading a Plot with FormPage

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I am using `FormPage` to generate a DateListPlot with the TimeSeries of "ConfirmedCases" by Country. The code which I am using is

```
CloudDeploy@FormPage[
  {
   "pais" -> <|"Interpreter" -> "Country", "Label" -> "País", 
     "Input" -> "Colombia"|>
   },
  Module[{data, image, label},
    data = 
     ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19", 
       "WorldCountries"][SelectFirst[(#Country == p &) /. p -> #pais],
       "ConfirmedCases"];
    label = EntityValue[#pais, "Name"];
    image = DateListPlot[data,
      PlotStyle -> Thick,
      PlotLabel -> label];
    Show[image]
    ] &
  ]
```

But **sometimes** the graphic is showing incomplete, without ticks, even several times the problem persist. Here is he link generated.
https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/49564e91-774a-4df0-9d0d-261616db8fe8

This is an example of an incomplete graphics generated in the FormPage.

[image]

I would like to know how to solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2049593). I tried the link several times with many different countries and I was unable to reproduce the problem. What browser are you using? I used Chrome Version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I am using Chrome Versión 84.0.4147.105 (Build oficial) (64 bits). I just tried again and I obtained the same problem. It occurs sometimes, and then I update the page the problem persists. I don't know why this happens, but the problem is just as is shown in the figure of Mexico, the plot appears without ticks.